# .Owl Carousel issue after Migrating Word press from localhost to AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, wordpress-theming, bitnami

I'm new to all things Website building/customising, complete beginner learning on the go (literally YouTube and google are a very good friend of mine at them moment)
I have just finished migration from the Wamp localhost to Bitnami WordPress (AWS EC2) using the All-in-one Migration plugin, I am using the Electro (child) theme, however my carousel sections are not working with AWS version of the site, upon inspecting the elements of both the localhost and the AWS site it appears a "segment" is missing I have taken screenshot and highlighted the segment that doesn't appear on the AWS site,

If somebody on here could advise me on the best way to solve this I would be so grateful, as I am trying to google the answers but I haven't exactly found the answer (probably due to my website knowledge)

Thank you in advance
Ashley

[Localhost site with the missing line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgeI1.png)

Comment: Have you checked admin panel ? Is it showing there fine ?

Comment: Hi there, when you say have I checked the admin panel, do you mean loggin into the wordpress site as the administrator? or through the phpmyadmin? (sorry my general knowledge for this is very slim) Thanks for your time.